# How to edit existing mailItem using WordEditor in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, email, ms-word, outlook, rtf

I want to edit my received mails to add links.

If the emails are plain text or HTML I edit the appropriate `msg.Body` or `msg.HTMLBody`.
For Rich Text, editing RTFBody directly seems complicated and crashes my Outlook.

I can edit the HTMLBody of Rich Text mails, but it then converts the whole mail to HTML which makes it change appearance and can't handle embedded attachments well.

MSDN talks about MailItem.GetInspector, which returns WordEditor and allows a much easier way of editing documents.

All examples I found are of new mails being created, not existing being edited.

The following code:

```
Set objInsp = itm.GetInspector
Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
objDoc.Characters(1).InsertBefore "string"
```

Generates the following error:

> Run-time error '4605', This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing.

How do I unlock the mailitem to allow for editing?
Is there an alternatively way to edit RTFBody?

I tried to set the objDoc.ProtectionType to allow writing, but it also says I cannot change the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing exactly the same issue ([Outlook VBA: Replace inline object with text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23824341/2707864)).
As posted in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824341/outlook-vba-replace-inline-object-with-text#comment36750655_23824341) (soon to be edited to a more polished version, after further testing), you have to use `objDoc.UnProtect` prior to modifying contents.
I have actually used

```
'On Error Resume Next   ' This will prevent the error message... risky!
Dim odProt As Integer
odProt = objDoc.ProtectionType
If (odProt <> wdNoProtection) Then
    Debug.Print "Document is protected with type " & odProt & ", unprotecting temporarily"
    objDoc.UnProtect
End If
' ... Write your code
If (odProt <> wdNoProtection) Then
    Debug.Print "Restoring protection"
    objDoc.Protect (odProt)
End If
objMsg.Display
objMsg.Save
```

I am not sure if the last two lines are the best, but it worked for me.

Note that having `On Error Resume Next` will prevent the error message, and you may see that none of your editions has any effect without apparent reason.

Comment: I actually got Run-time error 4605 on objDoc.Protect part, saying that the command is not available. But for the purpose of the editing I needed, it seemed fine to just leave the document unprotected.

Comment: @RipperDoc - Thanks for the feedback. It may be the case that in following Outlook sessions your `objDoc` is anyway `Protected`. You might find your situation inconvenient only under specific circumstances, depending on the actions you want to perform in your macro (and it seems not to be your case).