# VBA Excel - Pasting a Chart in Outlook Mail Body (Not as image)

Tags: excel, vba, charts, outlook

I'm trying to paste a chart to a new e-mail through outlook using Excel VBA. It can't be sent as an image because it looses too much resolution.
The way I need it to be done is like I do manually, just copying and pasting (ctrl +c, ctrl + v):

[image]

The code I have follows:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Somatório_bacias").ChartObjects(1).Copy

'Envia o e-mail
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
   .To = "myemail@gmail.com"
   .Cc = ""
   .Subject = ""

   'Chart part goes around here

   .send   '.send or use .Display
End With
```

Does someone have a solution that isn't using images?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed.

```
With OutMail
    'Display message to allow access to the Word Document Object Model
    .Display
   .To = "myemail@gmail.com"
   .Cc = ""
   .Subject = ""
   'Access the Word Document Object Module
    With .GetInspector.WordEditor
        'Go to the end of the email (optional)
        .Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=6 'wdStory
        'Add a new line (optional)
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        'Add a new line (optional)
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        'Paste the chart into the body of the email
        .Application.Selection.Paste
    End With
   .send
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I'm getting the error 'Run-time error ‘4605’ This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing'  on the .application lines. Also the .unprotect doesn't work, it says that it is already unprotected. Any idea how to unlock the document?

Comment: See whether the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510335/how-to-edit-existing-mailitem-using-wordeditor-in-outlook-vba/23875246) helps.