# VBA find/replace code .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll is not working

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I am working on export Outlook email able date to excel sheet. But encountered `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` error. I have enabled necessary

Comment: You need to correctly qualify objects and constants when you are working with an object model that is not the host object model

Comment: @freeflow Can tell more details? I am new for VBA

Comment: So many pictures, all irrelevant. *What* is the error?

Comment: @GSerg the last picture is the error

Comment: No, the last picture *supposedly* shows *where* the error is, not *what* it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved with below code

```
 Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(mypath)
xExcelApp.Visible = True
Set xWs = xWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 xWs.Activate
Set oLookwordTbl = oLookWordDoc.Tables(1)    'Grab the word table
colcount = oLookwordTbl.Columns.Count
For iRow = 2 To oLookwordTbl.Rows.Count         
 'oLookwordTbl.Rows(iRow).Range.Copy
    For icol = 1 To colcount
        cellvalue = oLookwordTbl.Cell(iRow, icol)
        cellvalue = Replace(cellvalue, Chr(13), "")
        cellvalue = Replace(cellvalue, Chr(10), "")
        cellvalue = Replace(cellvalue, Chr(244), "")
        cellvalue = Replace(cellvalue, "^p", "")
        cellvalue = Left(cellvalue, Len(cellvalue) - 1)
        xWs.Cells(iRow, icol).Value = cellvalue
    Next
Next
xWs.Cells(xWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to unprotect mail message before editing
(answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875246/14907151)

```
...
Set oLookWordDoc = oLookInspector.WordEditor
oLookWordDoc.UnProtect
...
```